# Check if git branch exists in bash: weird interpolation behavior

Tags: git, bash, shell, git-branch

I'm trying to see if a certain branch exists within a shell script.

However, `git-branch` seems to modify its output when interpolated. (I don't know the exact phenomenon or terminology here)

For example, I'm trying to get the array of branches:

```
$ git branch
  develop
* master

$ branches=`git branch`
$ echo $branches
develop compiler.sh HOSTNAME index.html master

$ echo `git branch`
develop compiler.sh HOSTNAME index.html master
```

A kind of `ls-files` seems to be getting in the way. How come? Is this Bash? Git? I'm confused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output of `git branch` contains the `*` character, which signifies your current branch:

```
$ git branch
develop
*  master
```

Running just `echo *` in your shell will print a glob of your working directory:

```
compiler.sh HOSTNAME index.html
```

So your original problem arises because, after expansion, you're actually running `echo develop *  master`.

To avoid this directory-globbing behavior, you could just strong-quote `branches` during `echo`:

```
$ branches=`git branch`
$ echo "$branches"
develop
*  master
```

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this :

```
branches=$(git branch | sed 's/\(\*| \)//g')
```

I recommend you to use `sed`, because the `*` character is a `glob` for the `shell`, so it's expanded to all files and dir in the current directory. Moreover, I remove not needed extra spaces.